# Download app from App Store to use as backup/rollback

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to download an app from the App Store to have as a fallback if I don't have the original code/binary?

Comment: What do you mean with backup/rollback? You want to get the source code from a version in the appstore? This is not possible, you might get the assembler code from a binary but never the real source.

Comment: This would be a dirty work around. You as a developer have to ensure that you always have up-to-date backups

Comment: The app that is in the App Store was written by another company. I'm not looking for the source code, just to be able to re-submit the old version. If there is a work around, dirty or not, I would love to know it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I beg to differ... Should any questions that us devs have about Apple's App Store, or any other app store, have no bearing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. You cannot simply download the app with the iTunes.app and then submit it in the future. You need to have the source code, to be able to re-submit the app in the future.

More info on how to (re-)submit an app: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH38-SW1